# App Compatibility doesn't work on iPhone 5c

Tags: iphone, applications, upgrade, compatibility, ios

The **App Compatibility** feature was designed by Apple [to list the apps that won't work after a new update is released](https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/19/16332562/ios-11-32-64-bit-apps-update-wont-work-apple-iphone), and you can find it by accessing **Settings** > **General** > **About** > **Applications**.

It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

And like this:

[image]

As the owner of two iPhones, an **iPhone 6** and an **iPhone 5c** both on iOS 10.3.3, both containing the same apps, I have seen **App Compatibility** function on the iPhone 6 and saw compatibility warnings for some apps, but cannot get it to work on the iPhone 5c for those same apps.

I am now away from the iPhone 6, and would like to make it work on my iPhone 5c.

This is what going to **Settings** > **General** > **About** > **Applications** looks like on my iPhone 5c:

[image]

I cannot click "**Applications**" on that screen, or get any info on which apps are not going to be compatible with iOS 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 11 is a 64-bit-only OS. Apps that were only built for previous 32-bit iOSes will not work on 11, which is where the incompatibility comes from.

Your iPhone 5c is a 32-bit phone, so it will not support iOS 11. As a result, there aren't app compatibility issues for it.

Apple's list of phones supported by iOS 11:

- iPhone X
- iPhone 8
- iPhone 8 Plus
- iPhone 7
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPhone 6s
- iPhone 6s Plus
- iPhone 6
- iPhone 6 Plus
- iPhone SE
- iPhone 5s